# Flutter firebase chat integration in flutter app without google signin

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, chat

I am developing an application for users signing up with their mobile numbers. Now I have to develop a chat module in my app How to integrate **flutter firebase chat without google sign-in**.

I have tried with the anonymous sign but the user's chat is not stored in firebase. May I know the steps to use firebase chat in-app and how to integrate firebase without manual google sign into my application?

Answer (score -1):

Use the Firebase Anonymous Authentication method to sign-in the user anonymously when they open the app. You can use the following code to sign-in the user anonymously:

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Future<String> signInAnonymously() async {
UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
    return userCredential.user.uid;
}
```